# Proof check: Sylvester's law of inertia

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, symmetric-matrices

I was trying to prove the following:

> Claim(Sylvester's law of inertia): Let $A$ be a real $n\times n$ symmetric matrix. It is known that there exists an invertible real matrix $P$ such that $$P^tAP=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
> I_{p}\\
>  & -I_{m}\\
>  &  & 0_{z}
> \end{array}\right].$$The numbers $p,m,z$ are independent of choice of $P$.

I think I could prove it; in a pretty straight forward manner, actually. But I cannot find any reference that uses the same argument as mine, and I am a little uncertain whether my proof is really correct. Below I will write my proof. I would like to know whether it is valid. Any critique/advice/comment is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**(My proof)**
Let $V=\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $(\ ,):V\times V\to \mathbb R$ be the symmetric form given by the equation $(X,Y)=X^tAY$. Suppose that $P_j$, for $j=1,2$, are real invertible matrices such that $${P_j}^tAP_j=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
I_{p_j}\\
 & -I_{m_j}\\
 &  & 0_{z_j}
\end{array}\right].$$
Our goal is to prove that $(p_1,m_1,z_1)=(p_2,m_2,z_2)$.

Let $W_{j,+},\ W_{j,-},\ W_{j,0}$ denote the subspaces of $V$ spanned by the first $p_j$ columns, the next $m_j$ columns, and the last $z_j$ columns of $P_j$, respectively. Then we have 
$$V=W_{j,+}\oplus W_{j,-}\oplus W_{j,0}.$$ 
It follows that 
$$W_{1,+}=(W_{1,+}\cap W_{2,+})\oplus (W_{1,+}\cap W_{2,-})\oplus (W_{1,+}\cap W_{2,0}).$$
Now the form $(\ ,)$ is positive definite on $W_{j,+}$, negative definite on $W_{j,-}$, and zero on $W_{j,0}$; thus $W_{1,+}\cap W_{2,-}=W_{1,+}\cap W_{2,0}=\{0\}$. It follows that $W_{1,+}=W_{1,+}\cap W_{2,+}$, so that $p_1\leq p_2.$ Symmetry proves that $p_1=p_2$.

An entirely similar argument proves that $m_1=m_2$. The claim follows. $\square$

Comment: I don't see the line after "it follows that".

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Oh yes, you are right. I now see why my proof is not valid. Thanks.